# How to create "move items animation" looklike facebook chat?

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook, animation

i'm trying to creat animation looklike facebook chat.

Like this: [Move items](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NHuRNsh8Sbc#start=2:03;end=2:09;cycles=-1;autoreplay=true;showoptions=true). Start at 2:03 and end 2:09.

I tried to set frame and time for 2nd item. But it didn't work.

Any ideas to make this animation?

Comment: What on earth are you talking about? What kind of "move items" animation should we find from the 5 minute time video?

Comment: LoL, sorry about this. i set: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NHuRNsh8Sbc#start=2:03;end=2:09;cycles=-1;autoreplay=true;showoptions=false . but it is not work.

Answer (score 0):

I got what you mean. Basically, you have to see into the `UIGestureRecognizer` class. This isn't the animation - this is the [UIPanGestureRecognizer](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIPanGestureRecognizer_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/UIPanGestureRecognizer). Just try it out - it's quite simple.